# Unable to convert VB6 to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, vb6, vb6-migration

When I try to open .vbp file (from Visual Basic 6) in Visual Basic 2008 and click next, next ... I receive error message:

"Could not load referenced component comctl32.ocx mshflxgd.ocx"

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: please see the link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318597

Comment: Not working... I have VB6 but without effect...

Comment: To do a 'proper' conversion from vb6 to vb.net, even if you were loading those COM controls, you should be removing and replacing them with the appropriate .net controls.  You'll have to be changing the code around the controls, too (the control's properties, methods, and events) since there are differences. So one way to regard this is the error message is not relevant. (Of course, what constitutes a 'proper' conversion is a topic that has a lot of subjective debate)

Comment: I receive error message:

'Connect' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'

When I click on the error, He send me to this code:

datPrimaryRS.Connect = ""
I do not know inside the quotation marks if there must be some code?

When I click the right button on dat Primary.Connect = "" -> Go to Definition, it sent me this code:

Public WithEvents datPrimaryRS As System.Windows.Forms.Label

Comment: The 2008 converter has probably changed some of your controls to Labels because it is unable to load the OCX files which are used for those controls. You need to get the OCX files installed for use on the computer where you are doing the conversion. Have you installed VB6 on the same computer where you have VB 2008? Have you tried opening the VBP in VB6 and does it work?

Comment: @MarkL The error message is relevant because the VB2008 converter works better if it is able to load the OCXs. It can help you move to the appropriate .Net controls but only if it can load the OCXs.